# CSS @import not working with PHP

Tags: php, html, css

I'm using the following html / css to try to import PHP files to act as stylesheets. This is so I can edit the styles within the stylesheets dynamically. I'm new to @import, but need it to change the stylesheet depending on the display width for the current device. Are there any obvious errors, or can I not use @import to import the source from a PHP file?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title></title>
    <base href="http://www.shadespeed.com/loyalty_points/" target="_blank" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device.width"><meta charset="UTF-8">
    <style type="text/css">    
        @import url('../stylesheets/stylesheet_160_low_res.php')(max-width: 319px);
        @import url('../stylesheets/stylesheet_320_small_smartphone.php')(min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 479px);
        @import url('../stylesheets/stylesheet_480_smartphone.php')(min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px);
        @import url('../stylesheets/stylesheet_768_tablet.php')(min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1023px);
        @import url('../stylesheets/stylesheet_1024_monitor.php')(min-width: 1024px) and (max-width: 1279px);
        @import url('../stylesheets/stylesheet_1280_large_monitor.php')(min-width: 1280px);
    </style>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Prior to this, I've used a Javascript script which gets the display width and height and stores them in COOKIES, which PHP can read. The cookies are only set if they don't exists. The problem is, once the cookies are set, they wont change. I need them to be able to change if the page is refreshed, so the layout can change if say, the user is viewing the webpage on a tablet or smartphone, and they rotate the screen.

EDIT: I have just got it to work, by replacing the @import urls with the full URLs of the PHP stylesheet files.

```
<style type="text/css">

@import url('http://www.shadespeed.com/loyalty_points/stylesheets/stylesheet_160_low_res.php')(max-width: 319px);
@import url('http://www.shadespeed.com/loyalty_points/stylesheets/stylesheet_320_small_smartphone.php')(min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 479px);
@import url('http://www.shadespeed.com/loyalty_points/stylesheets/stylesheet_480_smartphone.php')(min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px);
@import url('http://www.shadespeed.com/loyalty_points/stylesheets/stylesheet_768_tablet.php')(min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1023px);
@import url('http://www.shadespeed.com/loyalty_points/stylesheets/stylesheet_1024_monitor.php')(min-width: 1024px) and (max-width: 1279px);
@import url('http://www.shadespeed.com/loyalty_points/stylesheets/stylesheet_1280_large_monitor.php')(min-width: 1280px);

</style>
```

I'm sure I tried this earlier, so I guess adding the headers to the PHP files was the key. Thank you very much!

Many thanks,

-Dan.

Comment: Are you sending out the right headers in your dynamic CSS files?

Comment: Possibly not? It's literally the CSS styles within the PHP files. I.E the first line is:
html,body
{
width:100%;
height:100%;
margin:0px;
}

Comment: You have set your base url to http://www.shadespeed.com/loyalty_points/, so it means that your first CSS file should be at http://www.shadespeed.com/stylesheets/stylesheet_160_low_res.php which it clearly isn't. Do you understand the base tag?

Comment: setting the base to http://www.shadespeed.com/loyalty_points/
works with the following:

@import url('stylesheets/stylesheet_160_low_res.php')(max-width: 319px);

etc works fine. Please explain why adding ../ to the start doesnt bring it back to the loyalty_points sub directory then forward into the stylesheets sub directory?

Comment: @DanielPrice **Answer your own question** and mark is as working solution, as other people might run into the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're sending out the proper content type headers for these files. Place this line at the top of these CSS files:

```
<?php header("Content-type: text/css"); ?>
```

Comment: I've just tried this - nothing changed. The page still isn't styled. The index.php page is in a sub-directory:

http://www.shadespeed.com/loyalty_points/ so i placed this within the head tags:
<base href="http://www.shadespeed.com/loyalty_points/" target="_blank" />

Comment: Use Firebug to check to make sure your browser isn't caching the files and thus not requesting the new file with the proper headers.

Comment: Just cleared the cache in chrome - still nothing changed after a refresh :/

Comment: No, it just shows the styles. For my display width, the 1280 width stylesheet should load:
http://www.shadespeed.com/loyalty_points/stylesheets/stylesheet_1280_large_monitor.php which appears to just fine if I type in the url. Maybe i should try placing this whole URL in the @import url?

Comment: I have just got it to work, by replacing the @import urls with the full URLs of the PHP stylesheet files.